# catch (Exception ex) block misses

Tags: java, exception

There are a few similar questions, but for C# mostly.

```
@Override
public void setExtraItemsDone(XMPPResourceConnection session) throws NotAuthorizedException 
{
    try
    {
        cp1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        try 
        {
             ...

        } catch (TigaseDBException e) {

                         ...

        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {

                         ...
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        cp2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        throw new NotAuthorizedException(e.getMessage() + "; method took " + (cp2 - cp1) + " ms", e); 
    }
```

I am basically looking to catch a MySQLTimeoutException and turn it into a NotAuthorizedException (while keeping an eye for any other stuff besides TigaseDBException and UnsupportedOperationException) in the last catch block. Somehow, java eludes my master plan.

Logs show a straight

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1754)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.addDataList(JDBCRepository.java:183)
at tigase.db.jdbc.JDBCRepository.setDataList(JDBCRepository.java:1175)
at tigase.db.UserRepositoryMDImpl.setDataList(UserRepositoryMDImpl.java:651)
at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.setDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:1152)
at tigase.xmpp.RepositoryAccess.setOfflineDataList(RepositoryAccess.java:1204)
**at tigase.xmpp.impl.XGateRoster.setExtraItemsDone(XGateRoster.java:370)**
at tigase.xmpp.impl.DynamicRoster.setExtraItemsDone(DynamicRoster.java:377)
at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.dynamicSetRequest(JabberIqRoster.java:178)
at tigase.xmpp.impl.JabberIqRoster.process(JabberIqRoster.java:329)
at tigase.server.xmppsession.SessionManager$ProcessorWorkerThread.process(SessionManager.java:2135)
at tigase.util.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:132)
```

As far as i can tell, the bolded line in the stack trace should have changed the exception to a NotAuthorizedException breed. What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't see a problem with the code the way you have shown it, but can't see that the provided stack trace would happen. Try with the debugger to make sure you are entering the correct catch block, or put some prints in the code to see what's going on.

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace. I think there's a **root** cause that is missing from the stacktrace.

Comment: nope, nothing missing, and can't use any debuggers / prints as the errors won't happen, or will happen due to too muchprints. I am pretty sure ihave exported correct .jar ... hmm

Comment: You should know the exact line that generated the log output above. Please include that. One possible explanation is that one of the higher stack frames caught, logged and swallowed the exception. So the exception was handled without bubbling out to your catch clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree. the problem is not with the code as posted. Check your assumptions. Are there other overloadings of XGateRoster.setExtraItemsDone? Try using Jad to decompile the class file you are running against. If you enable the options to show line numbers, you can be sure the (decompiled) source you are viewing is exactly the code that is executing. Do you know exactly where the log message you are looking at comes from? Maybe it comes from higher up the stack, after it is thrown but before this catch block and exception translation code are even hit.